# Visual Studio SQL Data compare: equal records, but it flag as delete/add

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm comparing two table's database data, using Visual Studio SQL Data compare, updating target.

Once it finished, I do rescan, and it show me delete/add on some rows, even if the are the same:

[image]

Why this? If I do an export as script, and compare the delete and insert, it add the same data on the records.

Also: the two tables seems identical (comparing schema), and also checking manually (indexes, data type, and so on).

Why it flags this way? How can I fix it?

Note 1: the target DB is Azure, not sure if its relevant.

Note 2: the key on each table seems to be multi-column, as

```
dbname (ASC), ipserver (ASC), numordine (ASC), codcli (ASC), codsoc (ASC)
```

This is the source table (on premise sql server):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyCustomTable](
    [dtscritturaquery] [datetime] NULL,
    [dbname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ipserver] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [numordine] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [codcli] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [codsoc] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [SS_dtcreazione] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtcreazionelistaprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtinizioprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtfineprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtchiusura] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtcreazionelistaprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtinizioprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtfineprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtchiusura] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtiniziocaricocamion] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtfinecaricocamion] [datetime] NULL,
    [KPI_1A_vel_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1A_rit_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1B_vel_predisposizione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1B_rit_predisposizione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1C_vel_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1C_rit_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_2A_consistenza] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_2B_corretezza] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3A_punt_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3B_punt_stampaprelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3C_punt_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [LT_teorico_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [LT_teorico_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KPI_Ordini_Stocksystem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dbname] ASC,
    [ipserver] ASC,
    [numordine] ASC,
    [codcli] ASC,
    [codsoc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the destination (Azure):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyCustomTable](
    [dtscritturaquery] [datetime] NULL,
    [dbname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ipserver] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [numordine] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [codcli] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [codsoc] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [SS_dtcreazione] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtcreazionelistaprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtinizioprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtfineprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtchiusura] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtcreazionelistaprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtinizioprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtfineprel] [datetime] NULL,
    [soglia_dtchiusura] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtiniziocaricocamion] [datetime] NULL,
    [SS_dtfinecaricocamion] [datetime] NULL,
    [KPI_1A_vel_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1A_rit_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1B_vel_predisposizione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1B_rit_predisposizione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1C_vel_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_1C_rit_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_2A_consistenza] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_2B_corretezza] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3A_punt_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3B_punt_stampaprelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [KPI_3C_punt_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [LT_teorico_evasione] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
    [LT_teorico_prelievo] [decimal](16, 6) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KPI_Ordini_Stocksystem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dbname] ASC,
    [ipserver] ASC,
    [numordine] ASC,
    [codcli] ASC,
    [codsoc] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In fact near "WITH" in the bottom, on settings the key, some details are different. But executing the first one on Azure make the same script (i.e. PAD_INDEX for example is not set). Maybe thats the cause?

Comment: Can you post the table schema? Especially data types and collations? When people think some things are identical, they are usually not

Comment: @Zikato added on the question, with some details.

Comment: Is the entire row's data *exactly* the same between the rows of the two tables?...is it possible it's doing a delete & add as a way to do updates?

Comment: @J.D. its exacty the same. I've compared the query. If than I refresh, it agains set the same delete/add, make no sense...